# Bitcoins sent and confirmed by blockchain. But hasn’t been recieved

Tags: blockchain

https://btc.com/57d2819220862abf8a54f4912f3f973f0041cf8c3d64e229ff6248417cad0e73

I have sent money from cryperium. They have confirmed that the money has been sent. But i havent recieved the money at the source. Please help

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So according to the blockchain link i provided the money has been recieved?  Is there anyone I can contact to help me with this? If the wallet is broken or isnt’t fully synchronised; is it still possible to recover the money?

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain is the truth, the whole truth and nothing but the truth. It is the only truth,  the absolute truth. It is incontestible.

If the blockchain says the money was received it has been received. Money that has been received with more than five confirmations virtually never ever becomes unreceived.

It is probably worth checking several different copies of the blockchain by using several different blockchain explorers.

If a wallet does not show this amount it means one of:

- The wallet doesn't know about the receiving address. Perhaps because the address was not generated by that wallet.
- The wallet isn't fully synchronised
- The wallet is broken in some way
- A person managing the wallet is lying to someone without direct access to that wallet.

---

See also

- Answers to other questions about money [not received](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=not+received)